# How to restore Android fragment view state

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have application **titles** fragment and **contents** fragment on the screen. When the user clicks on the item in titles fragment the according fragment is created and inserted to a frame and the selected title is highlighted in titles fragment.

Transaction is done with `fragment.addToBackStack()`, so when the user clicks the `BACK` key, the previous fragment is restored and inserted in the frame.

What is the best solution to restore view state when transaction manager restores fragments?

The problem is that I should highlight previous fragment name in titles fragment and I should know what fragment it is. I resolved it by storing view state in my own stack: when fragment is created and restoring on changing transaction backstack using transaction manager listener.

But this doesn't seem like the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

Before the answer, next time remember to add your code. Chances are my answer will not help you as much as it could because I don't really know your code.

This is old but anyway, IF I understand your question (and app architecture) correctly, it sounds like a case for interfacing.

Example:

add this interface as a member to the content fragment:

```
public class ContentFragment extends Fragment{

   public interface onFragmentTitleHighlighted{
      public void highLightTitle(String title);
   }
}
```

and have the title fragment implement it. Make sure to equip your content fragments with the title fragmnet, and add a call to `highLightTitle(String title);` in the content fragment's onCreateView(...) call. This way whenever a new content fragmnet is being added the title will be highlighted.